# Imap - choosing between plain text and HTML

Tags: imap

I am working on an email client,  and currently trying to render message body. In those cases when MIME object is of type ALTERNATIVE, we have two representations of the same data, namely HTML and plain text representation.

Now, there are several questions regarding this.

**Question 1**
What factors do we consider when deciding which form - HTML or plain text - to render?

**Question 2**
Are there any devices that are not able to render html or plain text?

**Question 3**
Can we say that we should always look for HTML and try to render it, and only in case of failure turn to plain text alternative?

Comment: Why downvote? I have researched this for a long time, but couldn't find any clear answer

Comment: You have three questions in one. Try splitting them into three separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. The sender sends alternatives in order of preference, best last.
2. Yes, particularly if you ask about rendering well enough to be pleasantly usable.
3. "We" can say whatever "we" want, and epecially so if the subject is as fuzzy as what constitutes a "rendering failure".